# JavaFX - How can i access a Node of a controller from another controller?

Tags: java, javafx, controller, menuitem, actionevent

I'm using FXML to create the program.
 I want to translate all my Views of all stages (for now i have 2 only) by clicking on an MenuItem in the main Stage.
I have :

> `MenuItem french;` : the MenuItem used to translate the Label. in class A (controller) 
> `Label name;`: the Label i want to translate in class B (controller).

can i change this Label text before it's even opened ? 
**So How can I access from the class A using french.setOnAtion the `Label name` to change its text ?**
Thanks.

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946651/javafx-pass-parameter-and-values-from-one-controller-to-another/28947120#28947120) helps

Comment: Does it work for 2 different Stages ?

Comment: Should make no difference at all.