# Why does my view no longer communicate with its controller since the controller was set manually?

Tags: javafx, model-view-controller, nullpointerexception, javafx-8, fxml

Ever since I manually set my Controllers the corresponding views don't seem to recognise my controllers. None of the view elements are recognised by my controllers and none of my Controller methods are recognised by their views. When I hover over the `onaction='#...eventHandler'` in my views it says there is no controller specified for the top level element.

However, I have set my Controllers (this is the main Controller and then there is another controller set somewhere else for a pop up window):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("foodDiaryView.fxml"));
        FoodDiary foodDiary = new FoodDiary();
        FoodDiaryController controller = new FoodDiaryController(foodDiary);
        loader.setController(controller);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Food Diary");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 720, 480));
        primaryStage.show();
```

When I run the program I get this error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at sample.FoodDiaryController.initialize(FoodDiaryController.java:72)
```

Which is coincidentally the first line of code that references an element in the view:

```
@FXML private TableView<Food> breakfastTable;
```

And then in initialise (`line 72`) which caused the `NullPointerException`:

```
breakfastTable.setItems(foodDiary.getBreakfastFoods());
```

Anyone who could possibly allude to why this is happening?

Prerequisites:

- I have to manually set my Controllers since I'm not using a no-arg constructor with my Controllers.
- I'm using IntelliJ

Comment: @kleopatra I did read this guidance before posting but I don't really know where the problem is coming from so couldn't produce an example. Would uploading this to a Github repo and linking be a good idea? If not, what do you advise?

Comment: Simply produce a short example that has/not the problem after/before setting the controller manually and post it here :)

Comment: @GeorgeBaker `foodDiaryView.fxml` is missing (restrict the example to root element & `<TableView>`), also it would be beneficial to see the parts of `FoodDiaryController` involved (`breakfastTable` declaration, `foodDiary` declaration&assignment in the constructor, `initialize` part setting the items). Also make sure you haven't removed a part causing the issue by minimizing the example. Voting for close for not producing a MCVE for now...

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong and I can't check right now, but I remember some issues when using setController and setControllerFactory. I think when you've specified a fx:controller in your FXML then you can't use setController but must use the setControllerFactory or something like that.

Comment: I tried using setControllerFactory following this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946651/javafx-pass-parameter-and-values-from-one-controller-to-another however this did not work for me, I still get an error upon load(). Thanks for the suggestion!